# How to pass values by reference in objective C (iphone)

Tags: objective-c

I have a very basic question. I'm a new iPhone programmer. 
My question is can anybody tell me how can I pass values by reference to a function in obj. C? I know how to do it in VB and C#. But don't know how to do it in Obj c.

Thanks

Answer (score 91):

Pass-by-reference in Objective-C is the same as it is in C.

The equivalent to the following C# code:

```
void nullThisObject(ref MyClass foo)
{
    foo = null;
}

MyClass bar = new MyClass();
this.nullThisObject(ref bar);
assert(bar == null);
```

is

```
- (void)nilThisObject:(MyClass**)foo
{
    [*foo release];
    *foo = nil;
}

MyClass* bar = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[self nilThisObject:&bar];
NSAssert(bar == nil);
```

and

```
- (void)zeroThisNumber:(int*)num
{
    *num = 0;
}

int myNum;
[self zeroThisNumber:&myNum];
NSAssert(myNum == 0);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong! But I think that in `zeroThisNumber` example above, the pointer is passed by **value**, meaning that a copy of the pointer is passed, that is if we change the `num` to point to another int the `myNum` will **not** change. We by convention say "by reference" as having the address of the original obj we can directly change it (by dereferencing it).

Comment: I really don't know how to pass a value by real reference in objective C as in C++. I always use the `*` and `**` as described by Darren, but still a copy of the pointer is passed as I mentioned in my previous comment (the work is done though). Of course this is a kind of theoretical issue.

Comment: In the zeroThisNumber example, num is passed by reference (although technically this isn't the C++ meaning of reference).  In this example the address of the value of num is passed to zeroThisNumber.  This allows the value to be changed within the method and have that change reflected in the caller.  What you are referring to would be a reference to a reference... as it were... double indirection.  If num was not passed by reference the value of num would be copied and placed on the stack.  Any changes to num within zeroThisNumber would be made on the stack and lost when the method returns.

Comment: For those wondering then how to use a function where you are passing a copy of the pointer- you call your function like this 

[self nilThisObject:&objectName];

Comment: I think this is incorrect. You cannot pass by reference in Obj-C. You can however pass by reference in Obj-C++, just as in C++. And you can pass-by-reference to Obj-C++ method arguments. See Peter N Lewis' answer below.

Answer (score 16):

If you use Objective C++, which you can do by naming your file with extension .mm, or telling Xcode to compile all source as Objective C++, then you can pass references in the same way you do with C++, eg:

```
- (OSStatus) fileFileInfo: (FileInfo&)fi;
```

Answer (score 14):

There is no passing by reference (in C++ sense) in Objective C. You can pass your objects by pointer, and for primitive types by value.

Example:

```
void func(NSString* string)
{
  ...
}

void func(NSInteger myint)
{
 ...
}

..
NSString* str = @"whatever";
NSInteger num = 5;

func(str);
func(num);
```

Comment: I totally agree! Always in C++ sense: Passing by reference means that if you change the parameter of a method (function) to point to another obj the outside world will be affected (param is just another name of the var passed in), and this cannot be done in Objective C without dereferencing the parameter, because always a **copy** of the pointer is passed to methods (functions).

Comment: In Objective C, dereferencing pointer of an object is extremely rare. If you wanna change the value of a method parameter, normally you use either of the following two ways. Frist, use pointer to pointers (double indirection, denoted by **), like in many NSError examples. Second, wrap method as a block. Then put the variable in the same lexical scope as the block, and denote it by `__block` storage type.

Answer (score 7):

Try this way :

```
    -(void)secondFunc:(NSInteger*)i
    {
      *j=20;
     //From here u can change i value as well
     //now i and j value is same (i.e i=j=20)
    }
    -(void) firstFunc
    {
       NSInteger i=5;
      [self secondFunc :&i];
     //i value is 20
    }
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean. The closest thing C (and thus Objective-C) has to a reference type is pointers. As the name implies, pointers point to data that exists somewhere else. In order to get the thing being pointed to, you have to dereference the pointer. Objects in Objective-C are never directly accessed — you always use pointers to talk to them. You can also pass pointers to other types than objects.

Pointers are kind of a tricky subject. I would definitely recommend reading up on C to get a feel for them.

Answer (score 0):

There's an argument to be had if you want to get more than one address from a resulting function call.  You can do so instead by creating a wrapper class and passing that instead.  For example:

```
@interface AddressWrapper : NSObject {
    NSArray     *array;
    NSString    *string;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign)   NSArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   NSString *string;
@end
```

In *.m:

```
@implementation AddressWrapper
@synthesize array, string;
@end



-(void) getAddresses: (AddressWrapper*) wrapper {
    wrapper.array = myNSArray;
    wrapper.string = myNSString;
}
```