# Objective C - Pass by value and pass by reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parameter-passing

First of all, sorry for this simple question. But I need to understand what is happening.

I thought the output should be **`upper case string`**. But it comes out to be **`UPPER CASE STRING`**.

```
- (void)test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     [self changeString:stringVar];
     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
}

- (void)changeString:(NSString*)string
{
     string = [string lowercaseString];
}
```

What is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `[string lowercaseString]` call creates a *new* `NSString` object that you assign to the local variable `string`. This does not change the value of `stringVar` outside the `changeString` function. The pointer itself is passed by value.

One way to do what you want, is to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
-(void) test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     [self changeString:&stringVar];
     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
}

-(void) changeString:(NSString**)string
{
     *string = [*string lowercaseString];
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, ARC would handle the memory handling even in this case transparently, right?

Comment: Dear Greg, This means Objective C by default uses pass by value mechanism right?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, ARC handles the memory management correctly (the compiler will warn you if it can't figure out what you are doing).

Comment: @charith: Yes, the semantics for argument passing in Objective-C are the same as in C.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the reference to the `[NSString lowerCaseString]` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseString), you can see that it returns a new string, with the lowercase'd characters:

> Returns lowercased representation of the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (NSString *)lowercaseString
> ```

What your code does is simply overwrite the reference to the input string with the output of the `lowercaseString` call, which has no effect.  The best way to solve this issue is for you to return the value yourself, which makes the method easier to understand:

```
-(void) test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     stringVar = [self changeString:stringVar];
     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
}

-(NSString *) changeString:(NSString*)string
{
     string = [string lowercaseString];
     return string;
}
```

You need to understand that `NSString` is immutable so there is no way, other than reassigning the reference, to change a string's contents.  You could, however use `NSMutableString` instead, which can be modified in place.

Answer (score 1):

I am referring to above given problem and helping you with the mistake.Find my comments

```
- (void)test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     //StringVar is a pointer to integer class.let us assume the address the stringVar be 0x50 and the value it has be 0x100
     //So 0x100 has the string 

     [self changeString:stringVar];
     //above we are calling the method to lowercase and argument is stringVar
     //As the method is called we pass 0x100 in the argument as this is the memory where the value is kept

     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
    //Our StringVar still points to 0x100 where the value is in upperString
}

- (void)changeString:(NSString*)string
{
     string = [string lowercaseString];
    // Now operation performed on string returns a new value on suppose location 0x200
   //String parameter passed in argument is assigned the new value.But we never pass values as we pass only location under the hood
   //New parameter passed now points to new memory location 0x200

}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With the new solution
-(void) test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     //let 0x50 be stringVar memorylocation pointing to 0x100 with above value
     [self changeString:&stringVar];
     //0x50 is passed in argument
     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
     //On new location stored in address of stringVar it points to new string value
}

-(void) changeString:(NSString**)string
{
     *string = [*string lowercaseString];
     //0x200 is new memory location received.*string gives the 0x100 location and hence the value
   //LHS is assigned to new location .On LHS you find *string which will be assigned 0x200
   //As string with location 0x50 is value 0x200 which will make it to point new      location where lowercase string exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string in `-(void) changeString:(NSString*)string` is local variable, modify method to return value:

```
-(void) test
{
     NSString *stringVar = @"UPPER CASE STRING";
     stringVar =[self changeString:stringVar];
     NSLog(@"value after changed : %@", stringVar);
}
-(NSString *) changeString:(NSString*)string
{
    return [string lowercaseString];
}
```

Comment: Assigning NSString to a `Void` method is an error and a `Void` method doesn't return a value

Comment: sorry, my bad, of cource return value is 'NSString*'

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a local variable (a pointer to an NSString which is immutable), you're just changing what `string`points to in the local function, but when you return its value will be thrown away.

What you may want to do is to simply pass the string as a parameter and return the lower case string from the function.