# Objective C: instance variable as reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, reference, instance-variables

I have a problem with passing arguments in Objective C. Here is my situation:

I have a root controller (main screen). Inside its view there is a ScrollView and it containts 3 views (next 3 controllers). You can sroll it horizontally and these 3 views inside a ScrollView are changing. Next I have one object which communicate with some hardware. There is a session and in/out streams. This object receives some data and I need to show this data in views (root view and 3 views in scroll view). Also root controller and these 3 controllers are sometimes asking for some data.

It means that communication object has to have instances of all controllers to send them data directly. But controllers has to have instance of communication object to be able ask for data.

I wanted to do that like this: Root controller creates 3 controllers for its subviews (in scrollview) and show them. It also create communication object and send to this object these 3 controllers (by ref). And also send to each controller instance of communication object. In this case communication object is able tosend data to controllers directly and controllers are able to ask for data also directly.

Normally I work with C# so passing arguments by ref is not a problem but it seems that in Objective C it is not possible. When I want to send references, it creates a copy and send it so I have two copies of object and I dont want it. I want to have references to one object. I tried to send a pointer - `(UIViewController **)controller` but it seems it doesnt work as well.

Can you tell how I should solve this? Next idea is that root controller creates 3 sub controlers and one communication object. This communication object will sending messages to root controller and it will forwardind this messages to right controller. And sub controllers will send messages to root controller and it will forwarding it to communication object.

Comment: You definitely **can** emulate references using pointers. In what sense "doesn't it work"?

Comment: Show some code where the unwanted copy is created. There should be no problem to work with pointers assuming that you know what you do. A reference to an object is basically a pointer anyway. However, I strongly recommend to familiarize yourself with the delegate pattern and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not copy objects explicitly the are passed by reference in Objective-C:

```
void addWorld(NSMutableString *stringReference) {
    [stringReference appendString:@"world!"];
}
```

passed by reference:

```
NSMutableString *greeting = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello, "];
addWorld(greeting);
NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
```

See also the answer "[How to pass values by reference in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344476/how-to-pass-values-by-reference-in-objective-c-iphone)".

Answer (score 0):

I am idiot. When I was sending reference, it was nil. Problem solved, Objective C is passing objects by ref. But still I am wondering if direct access of communication object to controllers and direct access of controllers to communication object is right solution?